# Error while Compiling Eigen library v3.3.4 with VS2017 + nvcc (CUDA 9.0)

Tags: cuda, visual-studio-2017, eigen, nvcc

I tried to compile the following code where I use Eigen and cuda at the same time and I get an error.

```
    #include "cuda_runtime.h"
    #include "device_launch_parameters.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <Eigen/Dense>
    #include <Eigen/IterativeLinearSolvers>

    __global__ void printWithCUDA()
    {
        if (threadIdx.x == 0)
        {
            printf(" Printed with thread %d \n", threadIdx.x);
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        // Eigen Operation
        Eigen::Matrix3d eigenA;
        eigenA << 1, 2, 3,
           4, 5, 6,
           7, 8, 9;

        Eigen::Matrix3d eigenB;
        eigenB << -1, -2, -3,
           -4, -5, -6,
           -7, -8, -9;

        Eigen::MatrixXd eigenC = eigenA * eigenB;
        std::cout << " \n Eigen Matrix " << std::endl;
        std::cout << eigenC;

        // CUDA Operation
        printWithCUDA <<< 1, 32 >>>();
        if (cudaPeekAtLastError() != cudaSuccess)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "addWithCuda failed!");
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

With VS 2017, Eigen v3.3.4 and CUDA 9.0, I get the following error

> eigen\src/Core/util/Macros.h(402): fatal error C1017: invalid integer constant expression

[Macros.h(402): fatal error C1017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zOSc.jpg)

In my original project, the Eigen code is separated in a .h file from cuda code but the error is the same.

PS: it works well

1. if I comment the eigen part, or
2. I use Eigen in a fully cpp project with VS 2017 without nvcc

Is this specific to VS2017 + CUDA 9.0 + Eigen v3.3.4 ? Because according to [Compiling Eigen library with nvcc (CUDA)
: update2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802560/compiling-eigen-library-with-nvcc-cuda) 
it worked for other verions.

Thanks

**Update1:**

Thanks Avi Ginsburg, I have downloaded the latest version of dev branch. With that version, I don't get this error anymore. 
However, I have other errors that I don't understand: I have just replaced the latest stable release version with the one here [The unstable source code from the development branch](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)
The full error is available in the image here [Error_Compil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVVlc.jpg) but it looks like this

> 1>kernel.cu
>   1>g:\librray_quant\issues_lib\eigen_nvcc\eigen_nvcc\3rdparties\dev_branch\eigen\src/SVD/JacobiSVD.h(614): error C2244: 'Eigen::JacobiSVD::allocate': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
>   1>g:\librray_quant\issues_lib\eigen_nvcc\eigen_nvcc\3rdparties\dev_branch\eigen\src/SVD/JacobiSVD.h(613): note: see declaration of 'Eigen::JacobiSVD::allocate'
>   1>g:\librray_quant\issues_lib\eigen_nvcc\eigen_nvcc\3rdparties\dev_branch\eigen\src/SVD/JacobiSVD.h(614): note: definition
>   1>g:\librray_quant\issues_lib\eigen_nvcc\eigen_nvcc\3rdparties\dev_branch\eigen\src/SVD/JacobiSVD.h(614): note: 'void Eigen::JacobiSVD::allocate(::Eigen::SVDBase>::Index,Eigen::SVDBase::Index,unsigned int)'
>   1>g:\librray_quant\issues_lib\eigen_nvcc\eigen_nvcc\3rdparties\dev_branch\eigen\src/SVD/JacobiSVD.h(614): note: existing declarations
>   1>g:\librray_quant\issues_lib\eigen_nvcc\eigen_nvcc\3rdparties\dev_branch\eigen\src/SVD/JacobiSVD.h(614): note: 'void Eigen::JacobiSVD::allocate(Eigen::SVDBase::Index,Eigen::SVDBase::Index,unsigned int)'

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `__CUDACC_VER__` is no longer supported in CUDA 9.0, and therefore  `__CUDACC_VER__ >= 80000` is no longer a valid comparison. I'm not sure what it is defined to be (I assume `#define __CUDACC_VER__ ""` to cause this error), as I do not have CUDA installed on this computer. Try the dev branch of Eigen, they might have a fix for it. If not, the check should be for  `__CUDACC_VER_MAJOR__`, `__CUDACC_VER_MINOR__` instead. You can submit a proposed fix if you get it working.

#### Update

The Eigen devs already fixed it in the dev branch (not sure when). They bypassed the issue with:

```
// Starting with CUDA 9 the composite __CUDACC_VER__ is not available.
#if defined(__CUDACC_VER_MAJOR__) && (__CUDACC_VER_MAJOR__ >= 9)
#define EIGEN_CUDACC_VER  ((__CUDACC_VER_MAJOR__ * 10000) + (__CUDACC_VER_MINOR__ * 100))
#elif defined(__CUDACC_VER__)
#define EIGEN_CUDACC_VER __CUDACC_VER__
#else
#define EIGEN_CUDACC_VER 0
#endif
```

in `Eigen/Core` and replaced the `Macros.h` line with `(EIGEN_CUDACC_VER >= 80000)`.